# tag-it inserting data from the clipboard

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tag-it

This is a question regarding [tag-it](https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it) jquery component.
Comma field delimiter works fine when I enter the tags via keyboard, but when I paste tags with a comma(for example - one, two, three) from clipboard it looks like a one single tag with a commas inside the tag. Is it possible to configure tag-it in order to recognize different(separated) tags in the scenario described above ?

Comment: Hmmm.. the plugin supplies a callback for the `afterTagAdded` event, perhaps you'll be able to detect tags containing the comma character in that callback, then split it by that character and then insert them one by one using the `createTag` method

Comment: Oh! The `preprocessTag` method might also be useful here. Just check if a comma exists in the supplied tag name and then split it and add them one by one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`preprocessTag`](https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it#preprocesstagfunction-callback) function to check the given tag and eventually split it in some tags and add them to tag it using [`createTag`](https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it#createtagtaglabel-additionalclass).

Code:

```
var $tagInp = $("#tagInp");

$tagInp.tagit({
    allowSpaces: true,
    preprocessTag: function (val) {
        if (!val) {
            return '';
        }
        var values = val.split(",");
        if (values.length > 1) {
            for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                $tagInp.tagit("createTag", values[i]);
            }
            return ''
        } else {
            return val
        }
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/GL6VK/

### EDIT DELIMITER GOT FROM OPTION

You can get the delimiter using:

```
$tagInp.tagit('option','singleFieldDelimiter')
```

Code:

```
var $tagInp = $("#tagInp");

$tagInp.tagit({
    allowSpaces: true,
    preprocessTag: function (val) {
        if (!val) {
            return '';
        }
        var values = val.split($tagInp.tagit('option','singleFieldDelimiter'));
        if (values.length > 1) {
            for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                $tagInp.tagit("createTag", values[i]);
            }
            return ''
        } else {
            return val
        }
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/GL6VK/2/

Comment: thank you very much ! One more question, is it possible to get delimiter's values from the component settings ?

Comment: Interesting, let me check it!

Answer (score 2):

You can Edit the **tag-it.js** library for a permanent solution.
try this
Add split pattern in options

```
splitPattern        : ',',
```

Now, in the keydown event function replace `that.createTag(that._cleanedInput())` with

```
var tags = that._cleanedInput().split(that.options.splitPattern);
                        if (tags.length > 1) {
                            tags.forEach(function(tag) {
                                that.createTag(tag);
                            });
                            event.preventDefault();
                        } else {
                            that.createTag(that._cleanedInput());
                        }
```